# If websocket messages arrive in order, why does 'sequence number' is needed?

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io

I heard that websocket messages are received in order, because websocket runs over TCP.

Then what is the purpose of 'sequence number'?

[image]

This is the explanation of sequence number in websocket.

But I'm wondering why does that sequence number is needed, if we have a 'in-order' received message.

Comment: What is this picture representing? It is not part of websocket specification AFAIK.It looks like it's part of some protocol build on the top of websocket. Your question is off-topic.

Comment: @rkosegi Is there no concept "sequence number" in websocket then?

Comment: Nope. How about reading spec first? https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455

Comment: This picture seems to reference a protocol that uses Websockets for asynchronous request/response - this is **not** the Websocket protocol itself... because the responses might arrive out of order (slower responses take longer to compute) and because several requests could be sent before any response had a chance to arrive, the "sequence number" is used to ID each request with it's corresponding response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence number allows you to map your requests to responses even if the responses don't come in the order you make them.

HTTP and other relevant protocols support pipelining.   Also there is no need for the request responses to be sent back to you in any specific order.  Each one may be processed according to its individual cost or dispatched across a server farm and reassembled in an order that is not predetermined.  Either way, if they are out of order you will need a key to map the response back to your request.